# Wordpress - Load several pages with featured images in same page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a page top down that load all pages in this main page and I do this for each page...

```
<?php
    $about = get_page_by_title('About');
    echo $about->post_title
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($about);
    $abouturl = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($thumb_id);
    echo $abouturl;
    echo $about->post_content;
?>
```

The problem is when the page is loaded sometimes the image is always the same in all places that have images. I already checked the cache.
Maybe I have to reset something when I finish loading each page.

How can I solve that problem?
Thank you.